# Add File to Xcode 4 application

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoa, xcode4, applescript

I have developed an xcode 4 cocoa-applescript application. THe application executes a number of shell script commands upon button clicks. I would like to execute one additional command as seen below:

```
installer -pkg "path to somepackage.pkg"
```

I am trying to find a way to included somepacakge.pkg in the xcode application so that I can call it without having to pull it down from a network drive. Is anyone aware of how I can attach or included a entirely seperate .pkg into a xcode application?

As always,
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can simply put the entire package into your Xcode project and add it to the "Copy Files" build phase. Copy it into your app's resources folder, then you can generate the path using:

```
NSString* path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"<package name>" ofType:@"pkg"];
```

Comment: Thanks very much for the response. That is exactly what I was looking for. I couldn't figure out the exact syntax.

Comment: You put it wherever you want to get the path for that resource. Since you didn't post any other code, I'm not sure where it should go in your particular project.